# Is it possible to use images in an Excel IF statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Quite a simple one here, but I guess the answer will be a resounding no!

I have a few symbols, basic clip-art, which I'd like to display depending on certain information.

At the moment, I'm using this statement to display Y or N:

```
=IF(B2>0,VLOOKUP(B2,'Student Data'!$A$2:$L$36,8),"")
```

It's a simple lookup which checks another worksheet to see if someone has entered "Y" or "N" into the relevant column.

What I'm wondering is this: would it be possible to display these clip-art images (I have them in .PNG format) instead of simple text? I.e. `IF VALUE_OF_CELL=7, DISPLAY IMAGE1`.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a macro and setup your list of images with a select case statement if you want multiple images
Here is one example for one image.

```
Sub imageConditionally)
  If ActiveCell.Value = 7 Then
  ActiveCell.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert ("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/db65e70ba85d47e867af6c9451e7ec03?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG")
  Else:
    Dim shape As Excel.shape
     imgTop = ActiveCell.Top
     imgLeft = ActiveCell.Left
    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
     If shape.Top = imgTop And shape.Left = imgLeft Then shape.Delete
    Next

  End If
End Sub
```

You might call this on the selection change checking whether the active cell was in the column you want this in or something

**updated this example**
The previous example deleted ALL shapes on the worksheet, this should delete only the image positioned over the active cell.